# Select hyphenated word with double-click

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-7

UPDATE: Per the recommendation below, here's specifically what I'd like to do:  If I double-click the mouse cursor anywhere from the "b" to the "n" of "blue-green", I want all of the word "blue-green" should be highlighted. How can this be done?  Currently, depending on where you click, it treats "blue-green" as three separate character strings. So, if you double click between the "b" and "e" of "blue" it highlights only "blue" and not "-green."  If you double-click the hyphen, it highlights the hyphen alone. And if you double-click between the "g" and "n" of "green" it highlights only "green" and not "blue-".

ORIGINAL: When I double-click a hyphenated word or set of characters (e.g. "123-abc" or "blue-green" etc.), only the part of the word that I double-clicked is highlighted.  I'd like the whole word to be highlighted.

I'm using Windows 7 Pro. If it needs to be done on a per-application basis, I'm most interested in fixing it for Google Chrome, but any Windows-compatible web browser would be OK.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but I happen to have been working on the same issue. Here's my solution, updated in response to @David's comments, so that it now also works correctly on Windows.

Not only does it handle selection in `<input>` elements, but it also  fixes a bug with apostrophes in Firefox, and handles a range of glyphs that can be used to represent a hyphen or an apostrophe.

You can find a repo with a more thorough [demo](https://lexogram.github.io/select-with-hyphens/) of the functionality [here](https://github.com/lexogram/select-with-hyphens).

```js
"use strict"

// Tweak to make a double-click select words with hyphens or
// apostrophes.
//
// As of 2023-04-12, None of the major browsers selects whole
// words with hyphens, like "ad-lib". Only the text before or
// after the hyphen, or the hyphen on its own, will be selected.
// This tweak fixes the hypen issue.
//
// Note: Firefox (at least until version 111.0.1) also doesn't
// automatically select whole words with apostrophes like the word
// "doesn't".
//
// In Safari (at least until version 16.3), a double-click that
// lands precisely on an apostrophe will select only the
// apostrophe. However, a double-click on any *letter* in a word
// that contains an apostrophe will select the entire word,
// including the apostrophe.
//
// This tweak also treats these issues.

// On Windows, a double-click on a word will also select the space
// after the word, if there is one. On MacOS and Ubuntu, only the
// word itself is selected. This tweak respects these
// platform-specific differences.

// In the comments below, I'll use the word "join" to mean any of
// the following hyphen and apostrophe characters:
//
//  * - (hyphen: &#8208;)
//  * ‑ (non‑breaking hypen: &8209;)
//  * &shy; (soft hyphen, which only appears at a line break)
//  * ' (apostrophe: &#39;)
//  * ’ (right single quotation mark: &#8217;).
//
// NOTE 1: It is not trivial to distinguish between a final
// apostrophe, which is an integral part of a word, that is used
// to indicate possession)...
//
//   She said, "Those books are Jodi's, but these are my kids'".
//
// ... from a closing single quote:
//
//   He said, "She said, 'Meet Jo and Di. These are my kids'".
//
// For simplicity, this script ignores both cases. As of 2023-04-12,
// all major browsers behave in exactly the same way.
//
// NOTE 2: Two hyphens can be used to indicate a dash—a character
// which indicates a secondary thought–and some writers leave no
// spaces around a dash. However it is never used to make compound
// words. "Two consecutive hypens should be ignored--at least I
// think they should."




;(function selectWholeWordsWithHyphens(){
  var selection = window.getSelection()
  // Regex designed to detect if the selection is just a series of
  // join characters.
  var ignoreRegex = /^[\u00AD‑'’-]{2,}$/

  // Regex designed to find a word+join before the selected word.
  // Examples: ad-|lib|  seven-o'|clock|
  // It finds the last chunk with no non-word characters (except for
  // joins) before the first selected character.
  var startRegex = /(\w+[\u00AD‑'’-]?)+$/g

  // Regex designed to find a join character after the selected word.
  // Examples: |ad|-lib  |seven|-o'clock
  var endRegex = /^([\u00AD‑'’-]?\w+)+/

  // Edge case: check if the selection contains no word characters
  // or - or '. If so, then don't do anything to extend it.
  var edgeRegex = /\w|-|‑|'|’|\u00AD/

  document.body.ondblclick = selectHyphenatedWords

  function selectHyphenatedWords(event) {
var target = event.target
var isInput = target.tagName === "INPUT"

// In browsers on Windows, a double-click on a word will
// select the word _and_ a space character that immediately
// follows it. We will need to adjust for this.
var lastSelectedCharIsSpace = 0

if (isInput) {
  var start = target.selectionStart
  var end = target.selectionEnd
  var string = target.value
  lastSelectedCharIsSpace = (
    string.substring(end-1, end) === " "
  )
  end -= lastSelectedCharIsSpace // true → 1, false → 0

} else if (!selection.rangeCount) {
  return

} else {
  var range = selection.getRangeAt(0)
  // If the selection is at the boundary of a tag – for example:
  // <p>The selection word is one of <em>these-words</em></p> —
  // then range.startContainer and range.endContainer will be
  // different.
  var container = range.endContainer
  var end = range.endOffset
  lastSelectedCharIsSpace = (
    container.textContent.substring(end-1, end) === " "
  )
  end -= lastSelectedCharIsSpace // true → 1, false → 0
  if (!end ) {
    // The selection extends to the end of the startContainer
    // and ends at char index 0 in the endContainer. Use the
    // startContainer instead
    container = range.startContainer
    end = container.length
  }
  var string = container.textContent
  var start = (container === range.startContainer)
    ? range.startOffset
    : 0 // The selection starts at the very end of the
        // startContainer, or at char index 0 of the
        // endContainer
}

var selectionUpdated = false
var chunk = string.substring(start, end)
var ignore = ignoreRegex.test(chunk)
          || chunk.search(edgeRegex) < 0

if (ignore) {
  // The selection contains neither word nor join characters
  // or is nothing but a series of join characters
  return
}

extendSelectionBackBeforeHypen(string, start)
extendSelectionForwardAfterHyphen(string, end)

if (selectionUpdated) {
  if (isInput) {
    end += lastSelectedCharIsSpace
    target.setSelectionRange(start, end)
  } else {
    selection.removeAllRanges()
    selection.addRange(range)
  }
}

function extendSelectionBackBeforeHypen(string, offset) {
  var lastIndex = 0
  var result
    , index
  string = string.substring(0, offset)

  while (result = startRegex.exec(string)) {
    index = result.index
    lastIndex = startRegex.lastIndex
  }

  if (lastIndex === offset) {
    if (isInput) {
      start = index
    } else {
      range.setStart(container, index)
    }
    selectionUpdated = true
  }
}

function extendSelectionForwardAfterHyphen(string, offset) {
  if (!offset) {
    return
  }

  string = string.substring(offset)
  var result = endRegex.exec(string)

  if (result) {
    end = offset + result[0].length
    if (!isInput) {
      range.setEnd(container, end)
    }
    selectionUpdated = true
  }
}
  }
})()
```

```css
small {
  color: grey;
 }
```

```html
  <p>Here is the nine-o'clock news.
  <br><small>with standard hyphen (&amp;#8208;) and neutral vertical apostrophe (&amp;#39;)</small></p>
  <p>Here is the nine‑o’clock news.
  <br><small>with non-breaking hyphen (&amp;8209;) and right single quotation mark (&amp;#8217;)</small></p>
  <p>A word containing soft hyphens — un&shy;predict&shy;able.
  <br><small>(un&amp;shy;predict&amp;shy;able)</small>
  <br><small>Soft hyphens are invisible unless they appear at a line break.</small>
  </p>
  <p>A double hyphen--which is rare--can be used for a dash, but does not create a compound word.</p>
  <hr>
  <input type="text" name="" id="text" value="The ninety-nine-o'clock news">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="" id="text" value="The ninety‑nine‑o’clock news">
```

Comment: The regex doesn't select words with apostrophes as it stands. After some playing around (I really don't understand Regex), I got it to work as follows:     var startRegex    = /(\w+'?-?)+(-|')$/g;
var endRegex    = /^(-|')('?-?\w+)+/;
var edgeRegex    = /\w/;

Comment: I see this works on elements like <p> and <span> but not on something like <input type='text'> since container.textContent doesn't include input values. What sort of tweaks would you recommend for selecting hyphenated words in the values of input?

Comment: Thanks for your work on this! Just a heads up that it looks like a double click on "o" or "clock" in "nine-o'clock news" is highlighting beyond the word (it'll get "nine-o'clock news") in this latest iteration.

Answer (score -3):

It's a standard through all programs that it will do that because they all run off the operating system's typing configuration/program thing. To fix it you would need to do something in System32. I don't know what you would need to do but I suspect this is your problem. You should probably go into more detail though about specifically what it is you want.